# plt.plot with more points but less markers

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a line with about 23 points,  for making the line more smoothly, I have to use **make_interp_spline** to estimate more points for plotting, but I only want the markers to be drawed on the original 23 points, for 100 points is so densely, is there any way to accomplish it?

here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

def drawPragnogram():
    data_10p = np.array([15.8, 16.0, 16.2, 17.5, 18.5, 19.0,
                20.6, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 23.8, 24.6, 25.4, 26.0, 27.8, 28.0, 28.8, 29.8, 30.3, 30.7, 30.8, 31.0])

    data_truth = np.array([21.0, 27.0, 28.0, 32.0, 33.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0])
    x1 = np.array(range(20, 42))

    stride1 =  np.linspace(x1.min(), x1.max(), 100)

    data_10p_new = make_interp_spline(x1, data_10p)(stride1)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(stride1, data_10p_new, marker='o', label='10%')

    plt.legend()
    plt.xlabel('Gestation')
    plt.ylabel('Fundal Height(cm)')
    plt.title('Pregnogram')

    plt.savefig('D:/jin.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can plot the two things separately:

```
# remove marker here
ax.plot(stride1, data_10p_new, label='10%')

# here
ax.scatter(x1, data_10p)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I have tried this way， but the legend is not right， I need to keep the legend right